# I can't see the sidebar of the website which used Tailwind

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-ui

https://tailwindcss.com/

When I go to this site, I can't see the sidebar of the website, same situation in any websites that use `hidden lg:block` behind css block dosen't work.

[image]

But in Arc, Edge, and safari, works right...

I have cleared all my chrome cache, but it does not work.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/118823772/https-tailwindcss-com-when-i-go-to-this-site-i-can-t-see-the-sidebar-of-the-website-it-looks?hl=en